# Defining ORM Relationships in Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, object-relational-model

I have 2 models `Animals` and `Species`. An `Animals` can only be related to 1 `Species`, and there can be multiple `Animals` belonging to the same `Species`.

For example, `bobby` is an `Animals` object that belongs to the `bear` `Species` object.

How should we define the ORM relationship in the `Animals` model, such that we can use `bobby.species` to get the `bear` `Species` object?

Also is this relationship called a One-to-One?

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from Base import Base

class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__       = 'animals'
    id                  = Column(String(16) primary_key=True)
    speciesId           = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('species.id'), primary_key=True)

class Species(Base):
    __tablename__       = 'species'
    id                  = Column(String(16), primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Definitely Many-to-One relationship as `Many Animal` to `One Species`.

You can use `relationship` to achieve this:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html